# Jest - Map through an Array of Items and test their Values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple Utility Function. It takes an Enum, and Transform's it to an Array of Objects shaped as `{label: string, value:string}`.

Here is the Function as well as the Interface it uses:

```
export interface ISelectOption {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  selected?: boolean;
}

const transformEnumToISelectArray = (object: object): ISelectOption[] =>
  Object.keys(object).map(value => ({
    label: value,
    value
  }));

export default transformEnumToISelectArray;
```

I have a repetitive Test. Basically, I check if the output of label/value, is what is expected, if I provide a Enum. Here is the test, that it is currently working:

```
import transformEnumToISelectArray from '../transformEnumToISelectArray';
import ISelectOption from '../../interfaces/ISelectOption';

describe('transformEnumToISelectArray', () => {
  enum mockEnum {
    FIELD1 = 'FIELD1',
    FIELD2 = 'FIELD2',
    FIELD3 = 'FIELD3'
  }

  let expectedResult: ISelectOption[] = [];
  let nonExpectedResult: ISelectOption[] = [];

  describe('ExpectedResults', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      expectedResult = [
        {
          label: 'FIELD1',
          value: 'FIELD1'
        },
        {
          label: 'FIELD2',
          value: 'FIELD2'
        },
        {
          label: 'FIELD3',
          value: 'FIELD3'
        }
      ];
    });
    it('should return an Array of ISelectOption shaped Object with correct `label` and `value`', () => {
      const response = transformEnumToISelectArray(mockEnum);
      expect(response[0].label).toEqual(expectedResult[0].label);
      expect(response[1].label).toEqual(expectedResult[1].label);
      expect(response[2].label).toEqual(expectedResult[2].label);
      expect(response[0].value).toEqual(expectedResult[0].value);
      expect(response[1].value).toEqual(expectedResult[1].value);
      expect(response[2].value).toEqual(expectedResult[2].value);
    });
  });
});
```

Please ignore the `beforeEach()`, I have more tests, but I ommited them. My problem and this is just an optimization here, is that I want to make it better. So, I though I would `map` through the Array of `response` and `expectedResult` using Enzymes's `.map(fn) => Array<Any>`.

This is what I did:

```
expect(response.map(index => response[index].lable)).toEqual(
        expectedResult.map(index => expectedResult[index].label)
      );
```

But I get the following:

```
Type 'ISelectOption' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
```

Does anyone understand this. Do I need to spacifiy an index Property on my ISelectOption interface for this to work? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.map()` does not send the index as the parameter to the function, it [sends the value of the array element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), in your case this is an `ISelectOption` instance. In your code, the `index` is actually your object. Changing it to this should work:

```js
expect(response.map(obj => obj.label)).toEqual(
        expectedResult.map(obj => obj.label)
      );
```